# Errores de compilación en mi programa

Tags: java, poo

Estoy empezando con programación orientada a objetos asi que pueden haber errores de principiante. El problema planteado es el siguiente:

Se desea realizar un sistema de facturación y para ello se quiere modelar las entidades factura y los items que la componen. Cada item tiene un nombre de producto, un precio unitario y la cantidad que lleva del producto. En la factura se tiene una fecha, un nombre de cliente que puede ser opcional y la lista de items que la componen. Se desea que en factura se disponga de al menos dos operaciones:

a. `agregarItem(String nombreProducto, int cantidad, long precioUnitario)` que agrega un item a la factura. Se tiene que tomar en cuenta que si ya existe un item agregado con `nombreProducto` y mismo `precioUnitario` no debe agregar una linea nueva si no que debe sumar la nueva `cantidad` pasada. Ejemplo había comprado 2 x Cocas a $30 y luego se hace un agregar un item de 1 x Coca a $ 30 se identifica el item de Coca y se lo actualiza 3 x Coca a $30.

b. `Long calcularTotal()`, indica el total de la factura. En caso de no tener items el total es cero.

c. `void imprimirFactura()`, imprime en salida estándar el cabezal de la
factura, los items y el total de la misma.

Agregue los constructores get y set que considere necesarios. Cree una clase Principal que tenga un método main que cree una factura, agregue 5 items y imprima su contenido en salida estándar. Notar que se utilizó un long para representar un precio, esto fue explícitamente para simplificar la realidad.

Y las clases que yo escribí son las siguientes:

```
class Item{

    private String nombreProducto;
    private long precioUnitario;
    private int cantidad;

    public Item(String nombreProducto, long precioUnitario, int cantidad){
        this.nombreProducto = nombreProducto;
        this.precioUnitario = precioUnitario;
        this.cantidad = cantidad;

    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        boolean bSalida = false;

        if (obj != null) {

            if (obj instanceof Item) {

                bSalida = ((Item) obj).getNombreProducto().equals(getNombreProducto());

            }

        }

        return bSalida;
    }

    public long getPrecioUnitario(){
        return precioUnitario;
    }

    public String getNombreProducto(){
        return nombreProducto;
    }

    public int getCantidad(){
        return cantidad;
    }

    public void setNombreProducto(String nombreProducto){
        this.nombreProducto = nombreProducto;
    }

    public void setCantidad(int cantidad){
        this.cantidad = cantidad;
    }

    public void setPrecioUnitario(long precioUnitario){
        this.precioUnitario = precioUnitario;
    }

}
```

---

```
class Factura{

    private static final int MAX_ITEMS = 100;

    private String fecha;
    private String nombreCliente;
    private Item[] items;
    private int cantItems;

    public Factura(String fecha, String nombreCliente){

        this.fecha = fecha;
        this.nombreCliente = nombreCliente; 
        items = new Item[Factura.MAX_ITEMS];
        cantItems = 0;
    }

    public void agregarItem(String nombreProducto, int cantidad, long precioUnitario){

        for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            if((items[i].getNombreProducto()).equals(nombreProducto)&&(items[i].getPrecioUnitario()) == (precioUnitario)){

                items[i].setCantidad((items[i].getCantidad())++);
            }
            else{

                items[cantItems] = Item(nombreProducto, precioUnitario, cantidad);
                cantItems++;
            }
        }

    }

    public long calcularToltal(){

        for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++){

            long total = ((items[i].getPrecioUnitario())*(items[i].getCantidad()));
        }
    }

    public void imprimir(){
        System.out.println("Supermercado El Dorado");
        System.out.println("Fecha: " + fecha);
        System.out.println("Cliente: " + nombreCliente);
        System.out.println("\t" + "Producto" + "\t" + "Precio" + "\t" + "Cantidad");
        for(int i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
            System.out.println(getItems()[i].getCantidad() + "\t" + getItems()[i].getNombreProducto() + "\t" + getItems()[i].getPrecioUnitario());
        }
        System.out.println("Total: $" + calcularToltal());
        System.out.println("Gracias por preferirnos.");
    }

    public Item[] getItems(){
        return items;
    } 

}
```

---

Y los errores de compilacion son los siguientes:

```
Factura.java:23: error: unexpected type
                                items[i].setCantidad((items[i].getCantidad())++);
                                                                          ^
  required: variable
  found:    value
Factura.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
                                items[cantItems] = Item(nombreProducto, precioUnitario, cantidad);
                                                   ^
  symbol:   method Item(String,long,int)
  location: class Factura
2 errors
```

Comment: Hola Esteban Quito. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Intenta reformular el titulo para que no parezca que la pregunta está basada en opiniones, ya que es un motivo de cierre. Mira [ask] para más informacion. Un saludo

Answer (score 4):

El primer error no es obvio, pero se reduce a que no puedes incrementar algo que no sea una variable. La sentencia

```
i++;
```

es equivalente a

```
i=i+1;
```

Por tanto, si lo que haces es

```
item.getCantidad()++;
```

el compilador lo interpreta como

```
item.getCantidad() =  item.getCantidad() + 1;
```

Que, obviamente (una vez expuesto así), sabemos que no funcionará; la solución es escribir esa línea así:

```
items[i].setCantidad(items[i].getCantidad() + 1);
```

Además, ten cuidado con el uso de ++, porque

```
int i=0;
item.setCantidad(i++);
```

es equivalente a

```
int i=0;
item.setCantidad(i); // ¡i es 0 cuando se asigna!
i=i+1;
```

Tendrías que poner:

```
int i=0;
item.setCantidad(++i);
```

que es equivalente a:

```
int i=0;
i=i+1;
item.setCantidad(i); // i es 1 al asignarlo
```

El segundo error es más sencillo: se te ha olvidado añadir un "`new`" delante del contructor `Item`